# Chapter style using tikz package

Tags: memoir, chapters, tikz-styles

I have found a code for a nice chapter heading style which I would like to use and if possible modify a little bit. The code uses the `tikz` package and a `\begin{tikzpicture}...\end{tikzpicture}`

The code works okay except for the **Table of Contents** page which is rendered with a more normal heading style. The issue seems to be with me using the `memoir` class, which I need to be able to use several packages and redefinitions.

The code works okay for the **Table of Contents** heading using for example the `report` class. But it does, as expected, show many '`Undefined control sequence`' errors.

As I am not that much experienced with such advanced coding, I would like to ask if it's possible to modify the code to be able to include the **Table of Contents** heading using the `memoir` class?

Secondly I was also wondering if it's possible to modify the code a little so that the chapter number is to the right and a bit bigger than the chapter title and with a image as background instead of a lightblue color?

Below is a minimal working document including some code that doesn't seem to work with e.g. the report class.

```
\documentclass[svgnames,,a4paper,11pt,fleqn,fleqn,twoside,openany]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e,anyfontsize}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}                       
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\makepagestyle{Uni}                             % Defines page header and footer from here to ...
\makepsmarks{Uni}{%
    \createmark{chapter}{left}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
    \createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
    \createplainmark{toc}{both}{\contentsname}
    \createplainmark{lof}{both}{\listfigurename}
    \createplainmark{lot}{both}{\listtablename}
    \createplainmark{bib}{both}{\bibname}
    \createplainmark{index}{both}{\indexname}
    \createplainmark{glossary}{both}{\glossaryname}
}
\nouppercaseheads
\makeevenhead{Uni}{Gruppe Fib10, 1-15}{}{\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{Uni}{\rightmark}{}{Aalborg Universitet}
\makeevenfoot{Uni}{\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{Uni}{}{}{\thepage}
\makeheadrule{Uni}{\textwidth}{0.5pt}
\makefootrule{Uni}{\textwidth}{0.5pt}{1mm}

\copypagestyle{Unichap}{Uni}
\makeoddhead{Unichap}{}{}{}
\makeevenhead{Unichap}{}{}{}
\makeheadrule{Unichap}{\textwidth}{0pt}
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{Unichap}
                                                % ... here


\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}                     % Chapter style from here to...
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{}
   \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape}
     {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}{0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-3cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=LightSkyBlue] (0,0) rectangle
          (\paperwidth,3cm);
        \node[anchor=east,xshift=.9\paperwidth,rectangle,
              rounded corners=20pt,inner sep=11pt,
              fill=MidnightBlue]
              {\color{white}\chapterlabel#1};
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{-60pt}      %  ... here


\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
This is some text

\section{section}
This is some text

\chapter{Main}
\section{Section}
Text
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{Test} test reference
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class `memoir` has a command for typesetting everything, which makes it extremely customizable. The ToC (Table of Contents) is typeset by the `\printtoctitle` (the LoT and LoF have similar commands: `\printlottitle` and... you guessed correctly `\printloftitle`). All these commands take one Argument, which is the macro containing the list name: `\contentsname`, `\listfigurename`, `\listtablename`. From the `memoir` manual, `\tableofcontents`, by default, does something like:

```
\tocheadstart
\printtoctitle{\contentsname}
\tocmark
\thispagestyle{chapter}
\aftertoctitle
```

So, to implement the new style we just need to `\renewcommand{\printtoctitle}[1]{...}` using the same definition you used for the chapters.

As for getting the title to the left side, it's a simple tweak: change the `anchor=west` to `east` and `xshift=.9\paperwidth` to `.1\paperwidth`. And finally, to get bigger chapter numbers, use a `\scalebox{<factor>}{\chapterlabel}`, instead of just `\chapterlabel`, I used a `1.25` factor, you can change it for whatever value suits you best.

### (Not so M)WE:

```
\documentclass[svgnames,,a4paper,11pt,fleqn,fleqn,twoside,openany]{memoir}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{ragged2e,anyfontsize}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}                       
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage[]{kpfonts}
\usepackage{kpfonts}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}

\makepagestyle{Uni}                             % Defines page header and footer from here to ...
\makepsmarks{Uni}{%
    \createmark{chapter}{left}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
    \createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
    \createplainmark{toc}{both}{\contentsname}
    \createplainmark{lof}{both}{\listfigurename}
    \createplainmark{lot}{both}{\listtablename}
    \createplainmark{bib}{both}{\bibname}
    \createplainmark{index}{both}{\indexname}
    \createplainmark{glossary}{both}{\glossaryname}
}
\nouppercaseheads
\makeevenhead{Uni}{Gruppe Fib10, 1-15}{}{\leftmark}
\makeoddhead{Uni}{\rightmark}{}{Aalborg Universitet}
\makeevenfoot{Uni}{\thepage}{}{}
\makeoddfoot{Uni}{}{}{\thepage}
\makeheadrule{Uni}{\textwidth}{0.5pt}
\makefootrule{Uni}{\textwidth}{0.5pt}{1mm}

\copypagestyle{Unichap}{Uni}
\makeoddhead{Unichap}{}{}{}
\makeevenhead{Unichap}{}{}{}
\makeheadrule{Unichap}{\textwidth}{0pt}
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{Unichap}
                                                % ... here


\newcommand*\chapterlabel{}                     % Chapter style from here to...
\titleformat{\chapter}
  {\gdef\chapterlabel{}
   \normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape}
     {\gdef\chapterlabel{\thechapter\ }}{0pt}
  {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-3cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=LightSkyBlue] (0,0) rectangle
          (\paperwidth,3cm);
        \node[anchor=west,xshift=.1\paperwidth,rectangle,
              rounded corners=20pt,inner sep=11pt,
              fill=MidnightBlue]
              {\color{white}\scalebox{1.25}{\chapterlabel}#1};
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{50pt}{-60pt}      %  ... here
\renewcommand{\printtoctitle}[1]{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node[yshift=-3cm] at (current page.north west)
      {\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
        \draw[fill=LightSkyBlue] (0,0) rectangle
          (\paperwidth,3cm);
        \node[anchor=west,xshift=.1\paperwidth,rectangle,
              rounded corners=20pt,inner sep=11pt,
              fill=MidnightBlue, font=\normalfont\sffamily\Huge\bfseries\scshape\color{white}]
              {#1};
       \end{tikzpicture}
      };
   \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
This is some text

\section{section}
This is some text

\chapter{Main}
\section{Section}
Text
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{Test} test reference
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Comment:** optimally you should use the `memoir` ways of formatting chapters headings (and all other parts), the mechanism is well thought. The `titlesec` package is, as far as I understand, for less costumizable classes.